# Why can it run in main method but not in servlet doGet method

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, hadoop, nutch

I indeed run Nutch 1.2 in eclipse EE. If I use Nutch API in main method, then everything is fine, it can run and the result is OK, but I just want to make it as a web project, so I use Servlet doGet method (didn't modify the programm, keep the same) , but after I click "run on server", it shows:

> **INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
>   INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
>   INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s).
>       Servlet.service() for servlet return_searchresult_webpage threw exception
>       java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection      exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:767)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:743)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:106)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:207)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:170)
>       at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:82)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1378)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1390)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:196)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:95)
>       at org.apache.nutch.searcher.NutchBean.(NutchBean.java:90)
>       at yuhao.return_searchresult_webpage.doGet(return_searchresult_webpage.java:63)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>       at   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) **<

Server is tomcat 6. It seems that it is a connection problem for Hadoop, Nutch uses hadoop, and I have "hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar, hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u0.jar" . But I didn't find that the 9000 port is occupied by any programm, and the tomcat occupies 8080, 8005, 8009 ports. I am really frustrated. Can anyone give me a guidance on what the problem is? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Check your firewall settings and make sure incoming connections on port 9000 are allowed.

Comment: check that the firewall are all closed

Comment: @nitind, I have checked the port "9000" is not occupied using command netstat -o -a| find "9000"

Comment: OK, why's it trying port 9000, and why should that work when it's not one that Tomcat's listening on?

Comment: @nitind, 9000 port seems related to hadoop, (see the full error log above), and when used in main method, it seems everything is OK.